# How to reverse the MultiLineString command to a list of arrays

Tags: python, shapely

Let's you have a list of coordinates that you can convert to a line string:

```
coords = [((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 20.0)), ((20.0, 0.0), (20.0, 20.0)), ((1.0569687968009744, 14.934839039628798), (5.671166148109483, 20.19191074287741)), ((5.159985296083214, 5.788534924043662), (1.818050229337418, -0.37120648178790816)), ((7.0017400619480945, 12.967260092075572), (10.96695601450711, 7.213267528511481)), ((13.884688806883744, 0.35179537762349833), (15.348360220796115, -6.498103101647066))]
```

now you can do the following:

```
mlines = MultiLineString(coords)
```

Which gives you:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 0 20), (20 0, 20 20), (1.200116278748922 14.84428055460748, -5.798466435712259 14.62200169463755), (0.6555662089127656 12.32427661303933, 2.553985876183362 5.598843696996065), (13.35396083234261 12.58544673080557, 15.13771022756384 5.812255232822563), (4.862372312454008 4.839458771128404, 10.04340607477727 0.1213240497574262))
```

So now my question is how you can reverse the action, to get a list of arrays?
I also saw this `mapping(mlines)` using from `shapely.geometry import mapping`. But I do not know how I can have access to coordinates not in the LineString format but also in a list format which is array elements of the same data type.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to specify (and tag) the Python package in use.

Comment: Adding a second question is not likely to result in fewer close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your coordinates list as a `shapely` geometry `MultiLineString` object:

```
>>> mls = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(coords)
```

Iterating over it gives the individual `LineString` objects:

```
>>> list(mls)
[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f7c10dcf850>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f7c10dcf790>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f7c10dcf710>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f7c10dcf7d0>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f7c10dcf6d0>, <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString object at 0x7f7c10dcf810>]
```

Then the `coords` method of a `LineString` gets the coordinates and you iterate over that to get:

```
>>> [list(x.coords) for x in list(mls)]
[[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 20.0)], [(20.0, 0.0), (20.0, 20.0)], [(1.0569687968009744, 14.934839039628798), (5.671166148109483, 20.19191074287741)], [(5.159985296083214, 5.788534924043662), (1.818050229337418, -0.37120648178790816)], [(7.0017400619480945, 12.967260092075572), (10.96695601450711, 7.213267528511481)], [(13.884688806883744, 0.35179537762349833), (15.348360220796115, -6.498103101647066)]]
```

which is that you started with except as a list of lists rather than a list of tuples. But close enough. If you really want the output to be the same as the input then:

```
>>> [tuple(x.coords) for x in list(mls)]
[((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 20.0)), ((20.0, 0.0), (20.0, 20.0)), ((1.0569687968009744, 14.934839039628798), (5.671166148109483, 20.19191074287741)), ((5.159985296083214, 5.788534924043662), (1.818050229337418, -0.37120648178790816)), ((7.0017400619480945, 12.967260092075572), (10.96695601450711, 7.213267528511481)), ((13.884688806883744, 0.35179537762349833), (15.348360220796115, -6.498103101647066))]

>>> [tuple(x.coords) for x in list(mls)] == coords
True
```

Comment: Glad to do so. If my answer answers your question there's a little "tick" next to it for you to accept it as the answer. This will help people find this answer if they have the same or similar question.

Comment: I believe I just did it, let me know if I did not do it correctly